# Quitar salto de linea en MultiCell fpdf

Tags: php, pdf

Tengo el siguiente código en `fpdf` pero no sé cómo quitarle ese salto de línea al `MultiCell`

```
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Columna1',1,0,'C');
$pdf->MultiCell(40,10,'palabras y mas palabras',1,'C');
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Columna3',1,0,'C');
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Pues sería necesario Setear la posición en el `Eje Y` antes de escribir `"Columna3"` , como al inicio le asignamos `10` , y el alto de la primera celda es `10` , obviamente la tercera celda debe moverse `20` .

```
$pdf->SetY(10); /* Inicio */
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Columna1',1,0,'C');
$pdf->MultiCell(40,10,'palabras y mas palabras',1,'C');
$pdf->SetY(20); /* Set 20 Eje Y */
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Columna3',1,0,'C');
```